# В чем состоит проблема при подключении swiper к react?

Tags: reactjs, swiper

Есть проблема при подключении библиотеки swiper к react 18, а именно возникает ошибка [Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wrapperClass')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'wrapperClass')](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LyIUG.png). Подключения swiper:

```
import { Swiper, SwiperSlide } from "swiper/react";
import "swiper/swiper.min.css";
const Slider = () => {
    return (
        <Swiper
            spaceBetween={50}
            slidesPerView={3}
            onSlideChange={() => console.log("slide change")}
            onSwiper={(swiper) => console.log(swiper)}
        >
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 1</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 2</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 3</SwiperSlide>
            <SwiperSlide>Slide 4</SwiperSlide>
            ...
        </Swiper>
    );
};
```

export default Slider;
Пробовал менять версию swiper на 7,9,10 (сейчас установлен 6). Изменять импорты, импортировать swiper в другой react проект. При любом раскладе выдает эту ошибку.

Comment: Пробовали завернуть текст внутри `SwiperSlide` в какой-то элемент?

Comment: А вообще на github есть [issue](https://github.com/nolimits4web/swiper/issues/5613), наверное перед созданием темы стоило попробовать поискать в гугле